# Sculpting and custom axis?

Tags: sculpting

i'm using sculpt-mode for terrain meshes. I can lock x and y axis in order to only change the z-pos of the vertices when sculpting.

What I'd like to do is (bit hard to explain): use a 'rotated'(?) coordinate system when sculpting. I need the z-axis tilted a bit for some parts of the terrain map.

I wonder if that is possible ...

Many thanks

Edit:

I hope the following picture helps understanding my question.
You see 4 meshes. I can sculpt the selected one the way I want by locking the x and y axis so sculpting would only affect the z-axis. I'd like to do it in a similar way to the other 3 meshes and move the vertices perpendicularly to the (their!) plane (so in this case the plane would define that axis, but it would be fine as well if the axis could be defined in another way). It would be ok if the different meshes needed to be different objects. But it would not be ok if I had to rotate the meshes for sculpting.

[image: example]

Comment: would be a bit hard to help solve your issue if you can explain well, can you attach some images of your mesh?

Comment: Hello Jorge, please look again, I added a picture.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, when you sculpt (I mean add or substract geometry) blender "locks" your current z axis (your top down camera) so i you let's say pull up you mesh it will pull up to your view

Comment: Sadly I have no idea how you could set a 90 degree view to every angle you wish, I guess I'll do just sculpt many different point of view. BTW What shape do you want to achieve? Maybe there is another work around I could help

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this board so I don't know why my previous attempt to answer was deleted. Maybe it was just to short last time so I'm trying to be wordier. Its a perfect solution to your issue because I use this same technique. Its a very simple but it works. and I'm being as clear as possible.

Instead of rotating the **view to your object**, rotate your **object to the view**, so that the plane you want to sculpt is aligned with the correct axis. That way you can still lock the x and y, and just sculpt along Z axis.

With the axes locked, you can see that the sculpted verts only move in Z axis.
[image: sculpt locked to Z axis]

You can rotate the object instead of rotating the view to keep sculpting only locked to Z axis. Rotated 90 degrees
[image: rotated object sculpt locked to Z axis]

Even if you dont rotate 90 degrees, you can rotate the object however you want and the sculpting is locked to one axis. The vertices are only moving up. Rotated 45 degrees.
[image: rotated 45 degrees sculpt locked to Z axis]

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.90.0 -> Sculpt Mode > In the Right Tool Menu Under "Tool" Tab > Symmetry You Can Lock The X And Y Axis For Vertex's

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for your answer. Please consider expanding on it ( [adding images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/199656/edit) for one) so that it is a bit more useful. Thanks :)